# How to boot into ubuntu directly?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, multi-boot, grub

I am dual booting Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10. The problem is that the system boots directly into Windows. There is no grub menu shown during startup. In order to boot into Ubuntu I have to press `ESC` on boot which brings a `Startup Menu` with the following options:

> F1 System Information
>   F2 System Diagnostics
>   F9 Boot Device Options
>   F10 BIOS Setup
>   F11 System Recovery
>
> ENTER - Continue startup

The above menu is HP specific diagnostic software (I think) which was installed in Windows. On pressing `F9` it will bring `Boot Option Menu` with the following options:

> OS boot Manager
>   ubuntu (....)
>   Boot From EFI File
>   Notebook Hard Drive

Choosing ubuntu brings the grub menu with Ubuntu, Windows option. Choose Ubuntu again from grub to boot into Ubuntu. I am on HP e026ax. There is no UEFI. If there is no other OS and just Ubuntu, it will display the grub directly.

Partition Table from gparted:

[image]

Of all the Windows partition only two are created by me, the rest are automatically created by Windows and HP.

Comment: I think you have installed dual OS in dual hard disk correct?

Comment: No, there is only one hard disk drive.

Comment: Try changing order in bios. Press f10 and go to bios there you can see boot options. I boot options keep Ubuntu first and then try.

Comment: There is no ubuntu in boot order. It's just usb, cd, hdd, network.

Answer (score 0):

In your  BIOS, check if there's any option for show boot order menu at startup. disable it.

Then from BIOS, change boot order like this:

Ubuntu (....)
  OS boot Manager
  Boot From EFI File
  Notebook Hard Drive

Then go into Ubuntu.
Open the terminal.

Customize grub

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

It will open file with lot of options. Add this line at the end

```
 GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

(This remembers your last choice and boot your last booted OS without your interaction.)

Find line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`. Place a `#` symbol at the start of line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` in order to turn the line into a comment.

Decrease grub timeout to your preferred value.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the changes. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano and type

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: This is correct. You need to unhide the Grub menu, and remember your last boot - or set the default to Ubuntu as you may not want to boot Windows that often. Mind that you may need to do this from a live boot as you can't get into Ubuntu now. If your live distro has a graphical boot-repair tweaker, all the better.